# Excel time sheets

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have an excel overtime worksheet. I need to work out overtime if they start work before 7.30 to add time but if starting after 7.30 to subtract time. As well as in another cell subtract time if finishing before 16.30 but adding time if finishing after 16.30

What would be the best function statement to use?

Answer (score 0):

Can be done easily using If-else conditions in excel-VBA.
Share some more problem details